# Foreach PHP with dynamic rows

Tags: php, dynamic, foreach, row, message

I used below script to add dynamic rows in a form.

```
<TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>


<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt[]"/></TD>
        <TD>
            <SELECT name="country[]">
                <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="passport[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

#### with the use of the following php:

> $chkbox = $_POST['chk'];
>       $txtbox = $_POST['txt'];
>       $country = $_POST['country'];
>       $passport= $_POST['passport'];
>       foreach($txtbox as $a => $b)
>       echo "$chkbox[$a]  -  $txtbox[$a]  -  $country[$a] - $passport[$a]";

That works fine, got it showing on my screen. Then I wanted to integrate it all in my extensive form, which I need to be sent off to my mail address... see my php example below (all the $_POST's there are additional). What would the 'foreach' code be to be able to send all the information from above mentioned dynamic rows to my mail address? And what would I have to add to my $message to get it visible? Thanks for your help.

> `$TripType = $_POST['TripType'];
>
>       $DepartureDay = $_POST['DepartureDay'];
>
>       $DepartureMonth = $_POST['DepartureMonth'];
>
>       $DepartureYear = $_POST['DepartureYear'];
>
>       $ReturnDay = $_POST['ReturnDay'];
>
>       $ReturnMonth = $_POST['ReturnMonth'];
>
>       $ReturnYear = $_POST['ReturnYear'];
>
>       $Adults = $_POST['Adults'];
>
>       $Children411 = $_POST['Children411'];
>
>       $Children03 = $_POST['Children03'];
>
>       foreach ($_POST['Check'] as $value) {$check_msg .= $value\n";}
>
>       $Comments = $_POST['Comments'];
>
>       $mail = $_POST['mail'];
>
>       $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
>
>       $message = "Booking\n\nTripType: $TripType\n\nDepartureDay: $DepartureDay\nDepartureMonth: $DepartureMonth\nDepartureYear: $DepartureYear\n\nReturnDay: $ReturnDay\nReturnMonth: $ReturnMonth\nReturnYear: $ReturnYear\n\nAdults: $Adults\nChildren411: $Children411\nChildren03: $Children03\n $check_msg\nComments: $Comments\nmail: $mail\ntelephone: $telephone";
>
>       $xHeaders = "From: $mail\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 
>           mail ("mymail@gmail.com", internet booking", $message, $xHeaders);`

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.  Your HTML doesn't include a FORM or INPUT/submit so I'm guessing that they are there and working.

```
foreach($_POST['chk'] as $num => $value) {
        $check_msg .= "$num = $value \n";
}
```

Comment: This gives me a result when it comes to chk, but no result when it comes to txt, country and passport. Is there a possibility to get the results like in the example, where the results (chk, txt, country, passport) are all lined up?

Comment: Because if I use a foreach for every value in the form, I would end up with a result like this:
0= 1= 2= 3=
0= 1= 2= 3=
0= 1= 2= 3=
depending on how much input in the dynamic fields and how many values.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$message = '';
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $message .= $k.': '.$v.'\n';
}
```